# Why does FedEx Rate API fails with SSL/TLS error?

Tags: c#, ssl, fedex

Our webapp with FedEx Rate Request API stopped working recently.

Now I have downloaded the newest FedEx Rate API C# sample project from here:
https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/downloads/sample/2021/standard/RateService_v31_cs.zip

It shows the the same error:
"The request was aborted: could not create ssl/tls secure channel."

Can someone help, what the problem/solution can be?

Thanks in advance!

p.s.
This is the page where from I have downloaded the example project:
https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer/web-services/process.html#StandardServices

Comment: It's probably because they updated to use Tls1.2, try using it in your app: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Which version of .Net are you running, and which version of Windows?

Comment: @MarkPM: Thank you, it solved my problem. It turned out, that this line was in my code, but in an old part, which which was not used in the final code. I put this line just before the request, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @MarkPM:

"It's probably because they updated to use Tls1.2, try using it in your app: **System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12**"